# How to merge a list of dbf tables into one in Python?

Tags: python, dbf

I want to merge a lot of dbf tables in my "Output" folder, into one table. Here is my code, but it doesn't work (error showed below).:

```
import arcpy     
import os

arcpy.env.workspace="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Betty\\Output"
listTable = arcpy.ListTables ()
arcpy.Merge_management (listTable, 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Betty\\Output\\ppt.dbf')
print "done!"
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\caobaijing\Desktop\Betty\Python\MergeTables.py", line 7, in 
    arcpy.Merge_management (listTable, "C:\Users\caobaijing\Desktop\Betty\Output\ppt.dbf")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3762, in Merge
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Datasets: Dataset ****does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Merge).

Comment: Please remember to properly format your code in the future.  Also, when you say "it doesn't work", that is not sufficient. You need to describe *how* it doesn't work. Does it give you an error? Does it produce any output? Does your computer catch on fire?

Comment: When my programs don't work, I reevaluate my incentive structure, using things like bonuses or reprimands to motivate them properly. A lazy underling is a sign of a bad boss. Of course when my programs raise an exception or segfault or return incorrect data, that's a different story; in that case, I debug them, by looking at the actual error, or the actual and expected output, rather than just treating it as "doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks for your reminding and I had edited it and I am trying to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who find this, the code works just fine. Must have been a path error or no dbfs in the workspace directory.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:/junk/tables'
listTable = arcpy.ListTables()
arcpy.Merge_management(listTable, 'C:/junk/tables/ppt.dbf')
print "done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work for me, listTable kept coming back with a blank result. Using ListFiles with a *.dbf wildcard did the trick.

I used filezilla to download a bunch of zipped shapefiles from ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/PLACEEC/

I uncompressed them into a single directory (C:/Temp) so that all shapefiles were in one folder. 
I have 7-zip, so I just selected all the zip files, right click -> 7-zip -> extract here.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Temp"
files = arcpy.ListFiles ( "*.dbf")
arcpy.Merge_management ( files, "C:/Temp/output.dbf" )
```

I opened the output.dbf in excel, I had all my data together.

Answer (score 0):

Given a folder with dbf files, merge all of them into a df:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from simpledbf import Dbf5
    import glob

    # list all files
    path = r'./dbf_folder/'
    files = glob.glob(path + "\*.dbf")

    # init empty df
    merge = pd.DataFrame()

    for file in files:    
        # load dbf into pandas df
        df = Dbf5(file).to_dataframe()

        # append df
        merge = merge.append(
          df, ignore_index=True)

    # save to excel?
    #merge.to_excel(r'Merge.xlsx', index=False)
```